# No entiendo la funcionalidad ifRoom en Android

Tags: android, material-design

Estoy creando una `ToolBar` con 6 iconos si en su xml pongo `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` menos dos, los otros aparecen agrupados en un dropmenu.

Entiendo que es agrupa los items si no hay espacio para ellos, pero veo que queda mucho espacio a la izquierda, pueden caber 2 o 3 más.

Si roto el dispositivo igualmente solo se muestran dos y podrían mostrarse todos ellos.

Mi pregunta que directrices se establecen con el ifRoom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` como comentas, indica que si hay espacio muestra los iconos si no los agrega en el menù de que comentas "dropmenu". Es algo que he notado en algunos dispositivos que en ocasiones parece no los agrupa pero eso lo decide el sistema operativo.

Pueden caber 2 o 3 más pero por guidelines en medio debe de tener cierto espacio para mostrar por ejemplo un titulo relacionado a la actividad/fragmento. Si pruebas en una tablet seguramente si los mostrara por el espacio que es mayor.

> **app:showAsAction="ifRoom"** Indica que agrega el icono en la barra si hay espacio para ello. Si no hay espacio para todos los elementos
>   marcados "ifRoom", los elementos con los valores más bajos
>   orderInCategory se muestran como las acciones y los elementos
>   restantes se muestran en el overflow menu.